# Error: Cannot coerce to an evaluable reference in coq

Tags: coq, compcert

I'm trying to unfold Mem.load and I get the error:

> Error: Cannot coerce `Mem.load` to an evaluable reference.

I wrote the exact same `Definition` of `Mem.load` as `load1` and is unfoldable.

```
Require Import compcert.common.AST.
Require Import compcert.common.Memory.
Require Import compcert.common.Values.
Require Import compcert.lib.Coqlib.
Require Import compcert.lib.Maps.

Local Notation "a # b" := (PMap.get b a) (at level 1).

Definition load1 (chunk: memory_chunk) (m: mem) (b: block) (ofs: Z): option val :=
  if Mem.valid_access_dec m chunk b ofs Readable
  then Some(decode_val chunk (Mem.getN (size_chunk_nat chunk) ofs (m.(Mem.mem_contents)#b)))
  else None.

Lemma mem_load_eq: forall (c : memory_chunk) (m : mem) (b : block) (ofs : Z),
(load1 c m b ofs) = (Mem.load c m b ofs).
Proof.
  intros.
  unfold load1.
  unfold Mem.load. (*I get error here when unfolding *)
Admitted.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `compcert.common.Memory` module defines several names including `Mem.load` to be opaque:

```
Global Opaque Mem.alloc Mem.free Mem.store Mem.load Mem.storebytes Mem.loadbytes.
```

This means it cannot be `unfold`ed.

Before trying to `unfold Mem.load` just say that it is `Transparent`, after that everything will work:

```
Transparent Mem.load.
unfold Mem.load.
```

Comment: I'd like to say that I'm sure `Mem.load` is unfoldable for a good reason, so the OP should rather reconsider their original strategy.